# Ajuda Request com Variavel VUE JS

Tags: json, vue.js

Utilizo o `v-model` para jogar o valor para a variável `categoria_selecionada`, possuo uma *API* que busca a subcategoria no banco seguindo o endereço conforme `id` passado, por exemplo passando o valor 2 ficaria:

```
categories/2/subcategories
```

A questão que necessito passar o valor dessa variável, passada através de um `<select>`, deixando o link de busca parecido com isto:

```
categories/{{categoria_selecionada}}/subcategories
```

```js
mounted() {
    this.buscarCategoriasProfissional()
    this.buscarSubCategoriasProfissional()
},
methods: {
    buscarCategoriasProfissional() {
        request.get(app.api + 'categories', ).then(response => {
            this.categoria_profissional = response.data.data
        })
    },
    buscarSubCategoriasProfissional() {
        request.get(app.api + 'categories/' + {{categoria_selecionada}} + '/sub_categories',).then(response => {
            this.sub_categoria_profissional = response.data.data                     
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove as chaves "{{categoria_selecionada}}" deixando apenas "categoria_selecionada". Talvez vai precisar chamar com "this." ou "vm." dependendo de como estiver o seu escopo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma [*computed property*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) que é montada baseada no valor de `data.categoria_selecionada`.

Algo como:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        categorias: {
            1: 'Categoria 1',
            2: 'Categoria 2',
            3: 'Categoria 3',
            4: 'Categoria 4',
            5: 'Categoria 5',
        },
        categoria_selecionada: 2,
    }),
    computed: {
        url_categoria() {
            return `/categories/${this.categoria_selecionada}/subcategories/`
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="categoria_selecionada">
    <option v-for="(texto, valor) in categorias" :key="valor" :value="valor">
      {{ texto}}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <p>{{ url_categoria }}</p>
</div>
```